# Transaction staying in REVERTED status

Tags: transactions

I'm a beginner in ICO and i make a mistake

i have 2 transaction with REVERETED status. What can i do to fix that issue ?.

Tx  ID No.1
0xa713a3bbadb029fd186302ef59b4beac04aa02bfd52e7647ddb6d557e73aee48

TX ID No. 2
0x310efedeea02d9232ba36a2f8499f83c1934d6b2068d4726778c1f7da59e66b9

Thanks you in advance

Daniel

Comment: As a side note, not related to your question (which I answered below), I would stay away from that ICO - neither ICO smart contract nor Helbiz token smart contract have their source code published/verified on etherscan, which is often a big red flag. Sorry for offtopic, just wanted to give you a warning.

Comment: Ok, but is late for me, have buy token already :( Thanks for that warning, it's appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

revert means that the transactions didn't go through.
You got your money back as well as unspent gas.

There is something very wrong with the contract or the crowdsale isn't available to the public yet: https://etherscan.io/address/0xe34e1944e776f39b9252790a0527ebda647ae668

Comment: You give me my answer, got my money back minus gas.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message for your transactions (that you can see here: 0x310efedeea02d9232ba36a2f8499f83c1934d6b2068d4726778c1f7da59e66b9) it looks like the contract ran out of tokens, i.e. all sold out.

It's hard to say more as that contract didn't have its code published/verified on etherscan.io

Comment: Thanks you. How i can verify if it's ok, what to check on etherscan.io Next time, i want to check before purchase token.

Comment: Check if the smart contract has source code published (source code tab), check if transactions from other people go thru, as a minimum